# scope child head/tail is null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on an AngularJs app, I am using a directive and a controller

the directive is responsible for fetching a list of sates and on select state a new list of cities are generated

now I want to make an edit scenario so I have the state and the city selected but I want to set it to the scope of the directive

**controller.js**

```
  if($scope.$$childHead && $scope.$$childHead.changeState ){
     $scope.$$childHead.state=$rootScope.state;
     $scope.$$childHead.changeState($rootScope.state)
     $scope.$$childHead.city=$rootScope.city;
   }
```

**directive.js**

```
app.directive('w34UsAddress', function ($http,$rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        state: '=',
        city: '=',
        changeState:'&'
    },
    templateUrl:'templates/usAddress.html' ,
    link: function (scope,elem, attr) {
            scope.states = [
                {
                    id: "AL",
                    name: "Alabama"
                },
                {
                    id: "AK",
                    name: "Alaska"
                },
                {
                    id: "AS",
                    name: "American Samoa"
                },
                {
                    id: "AZ",
                    name: "Arizona"
                },
                {
                    id: "AR",
                    name: "Arkansas"
                },
                {
                    id: "CA",
                    name: "California"
                },
                {
                    id: "CO",
                    name: "Colorado"
                }
 ]


  scope.changeState = function (stateIndex) {


       $http({
          method:'GET',
          url:'cities.json',
          dataType:'jsonp'
         }).success(function (cities) {

        scope.cities = cities[stateIndex];

        $rootScope.loading = false;


        })

            }
        }
}
    })
```

when I try to `console.log($scope.$$schildHead)` it returns null

but when it become `console.log($scope)` I found `$$schildHead` inside it and having the properties I need,

Could anyone help with that . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Double-dollar `$$` things are meant to be internal in Angular and shouldn't be used in production if possible (i.e. almost always).

The reason why `$scope.$$childHead` can be `null` (and one of the numerous reasons why it shouldn't be used for everything but testing and hacking) is the way Angular scope and compilation work. There is `$scope.$parent` but no `$scope.$children`. That's because scope hierarchy is built in surprisingly hierarchical manner.

Controllers and pre-linking functions are executed from parents to children. A controller is the earliest point where the one can get the hands on directive scope. The children and their scopes are just not there yet.

Post-linking (`link`) functions are executed from children to parents. If there would be a place where a parent can be sure that the children and their scopes are ready (except the cases when additional `$timeout` has to be involved) for their first digest cycle, that's the one.

The need to use `$scope.$$childHead` in a directive indicates that some bad design decision took place. The directive should be refactored to use the recommended ways of directive communication through:

- two-way `=` bindings in child directives
- context `&` bindings in child directives
- `require`d parent controllers in child directives
- event `$emit`/`$broadcast` (not recommended for isolated scopes because of broken scope hierarchy)